# m2eclipse plugin search gives no results when configured to Nexus

Tags: java, search, maven, m2eclipse, nexus

I configured Nexus to proxy for public repositories. Dependencies search works good but when I try to search plugin, e.g. "maven-compiler-plugin", it gives 0 results. Indexes are ok in Nexus and plugin artifact exists there.

Could someone please tell me how to configure it to be able to receive plugin search results?

Here are my settings:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>thirdparty</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have noticed this issue with the m2eclipse plugin when it cant find plugins that exist. I usually do the search in the artifactory instead of from eclipse to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. Whilst I haven't solved for myself, the following two pointers may help:

Take a look at the "Publish Indexes" section of the following link:
http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-tasks.html

From the documentation, it looks like configuring Nexus to publish indexes (e.g. on "All repositories") should do the trick. You will want to run the scheduled task manually once set up so that it does it directly. There may also be caching in m2eclipse/m2e.

I'm not convinced it's working, but I'm having additional issues with Nexus downloading indexes from proxied repositories. This may be part of the issue you're seeing, so take a look at the "Download Remote Indexes" section here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html